# Date and Time field query

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datetime-format

If Date and Time field is having date entry like '2017-12-04 21:30:00.000' and Duration is '1800' and '2017-12-04 21:30:22.000' has '22' then our query should show record as '2017-12-04 21:30:00.000' as '1800' but 22 seconds should come at '2017-12-04 21:30:00.000' but my query is showing at 2017-12-04 21:00:00.000 with Duration as '1822' (sum of 1800+22). I have this question is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777427/sum-of-duration-based-on-the-datetime-that-needs-to-be-updated-in-previous-half) in different manner but didn't get a proper answer hence asking this question here as I'm not able to modify in proper way.

Query:

```
SELECT Interval=(CASE WHEN datepart(MINUTE,[DateTime]) = 0 and datepart(SECOND,DateTime)=0 THEN
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),DATEADD(HOUR,-1,[DateTime]),101) + ' '+ cast(format(DATEPART(HOUR,DATEADD(HOUR,-1,[DateTime])),'0#') as varchar)+':30:00' as DateTime)
ELSE (CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),[DateTime],101) +' ' + (case when datepart(MINUTE,[DateTime])<=30  and 
 datepart(SECOND,[DateTime])<59
then cast(format(DATEPART(HOUR,[DateTime]),'0#') as varchar)+':00:00'
       else cast(format(DATEPART(HOUR,[DateTime]),'0#') as varchar)+':30:00' end) as DateTime)) END),   
      ID,Code,Duration=SUM(Duration) FROM Table
      WHERE [DateTime]  >= '2017-12-04 00:00:00'  and [DateTime] <= '2017-12-04 23:59:59' 

      GROUP BY (CASE WHEN datepart(MINUTE,[DateTime]) = 0 and datepart(SECOND,DateTime)=0 THEN
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),DATEADD(HOUR,-1,[DateTime]),101) + ' '+ cast(format(DATEPART(HOUR,DATEADD(HOUR,-1,[DateTime])),'0#') as varchar)+':30:00' as DateTime)
ELSE (CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),[DateTime],101) +' ' + (case when datepart(MINUTE,[DateTime])<=30 and 
datepart(SECOND,[DateTime])<59  then cast(format(DATEPART(HOUR,[DateTime]),'0#') as varchar)+':00:00'
       else cast(format(DATEPART(HOUR,[DateTime]),'0#') as varchar)+':30:00' end) as DateTime)) END),

      ID,Code
      Order by Interval
```

Actual table data.

```
DateTime             ID  Code    Duration
2017-12-12 00:30:00  1   12      1800
2017-12-12 00:30:37  1   12      37
2017-12-12 01:00:00  1   12      1793
2017-12-12 01:30:00  1   12      1800
2017-12-12 01:30:59  1   12      59
```

If I run the query then expected result is,

```
DateTime             ID  Code    Duration
2017-12-12 00:00:00  1   12      1837
2017-12-12 00:30:00  1   12      1800
2017-12-12 01:00:00  1   12      1800
2017-12-12 01:30:00  1   12      59

DateTime             ID  Code    Duration
2017-12-12 00:00:00  1   12      1800
2017-12-12 00:30:00  1   12      1800
2017-12-12 01:00:00  1   12      1800
2017-12-12 01:30:00  1   12      59
```

Comment: This is likely due to a language barrier, but, I really am struggling to translate what it is you're after here. I'm afraid posting your query doesn't tell us a lot when we have nothing to run it against. Perhaps you would be better posting some DDL, sample data and expected resultset.

Comment: @Larnu I have added some sample data with expected result set. Let me know if any thing required more than this.

Comment: 2 datasets? Ok. I can't see any rhyme or reason for how you get to those result sets though. There seems to be differing logic; for example I expected your last line to not exist, and the line before to have a duration of 1859, based on the logic of the first row. Your explanation, I'm afraid, isn't clear at all. You seem to be stating what you work, but not the why or how. Could you edit your post, **carefully** explaining the logic behind what creates your 2 datasets from the first?

Comment: You jump straight into trying to explain *specific* values without first telling us *what you're trying to do*. Even with the sample data, it's rather unclear. Try adding a paragraph at the top that just explains what your overall *goal* is here.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. Now editing my question for more information and with my exact goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date functions to round [DateTime] into 30 minute intervals, but the result does not match your expected result, which appears to be wrong

```
DateTime             ID  Code    Duration
2017-12-12 00:30:00  1   12      1800      1800 + 337 = 1837    2017-12-12 00:30
2017-12-12 00:30:37  1   12      37

2017-12-12 01:00:00  1   12      1793                   1793    2017-12-12 01:00

2017-12-12 01:30:00  1   12      1800      1800 +  59 = 1859    2017-12-12 01:30       
2017-12-12 01:30:59  1   12      59
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d50da/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([DateTime] datetime, [ID] int, [Code] int, [Duration] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([DateTime], [ID], [Code], [Duration])
VALUES
    ('2017-12-12 00:30:00', 1, 12, 1800),
    ('2017-12-12 00:30:37', 1, 12, 37),
    ('2017-12-12 01:00:00', 1, 12, 1793),
    ('2017-12-12 01:30:00', 1, 12, 1800),
    ('2017-12-12 01:30:59', 1, 12, 59)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
    dateadd(minute, (datediff(minute, [DateTime], 0) / 30)  * 30, 0)
  , sum(duration)
from table1
group by
    dateadd(minute, (datediff(minute, [DateTime], 0) / 30)  * 30, 0)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d50da/1/0)**:

```
|                      |      |
|----------------------|------|
| 1782-01-19T22:30:00Z | 1859 |
| 1782-01-19T23:00:00Z | 1793 |
| 1782-01-19T23:30:00Z | 1837 |
```